Multiple tenancy with nodejs, sequelize, postgresql
I am currently working on a multi-tenancy project. Our team has decided that each tenant will have its own database, and the structure of the tables in each database will be the same across all tenants. However, we are facing a challenge in managing the connections to each tenant's database. Should we connect to all tenants' databases and leave the Sequelize connections open? I am seeking a solution to efficiently manage this aspect of the project.
I hope i can find a good and easy solution to implement this

What if to go the other way? For instance to run a separate instance of app (or at least tenant-dependent parts of it)?

I would like to suggest the following steps. In case you can give more details on the challenge faced during your implementation, it will be helpful to analyze and resolve.

Create a config object that can contain tenant identification information
On every request, identify the tenant and build the context
pass the context in the request or create a new connection and set in the request context
use the resolved connection in the request to get tenant specific data

Note: We can use a middleware to perform the context setup or connection setup to talk to the database
